# Objective-C: Having trouble with Splash image and loading screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app I added a Splash screen, basically every time a user open the app they see the splash screen for few seconds then directed to SIGN UP page (if the user did not sign up yet), If the user is signed up they are directed into the app.

The problem I'm having is I'm already a **signed up user**, I see the splash screen, then momentary I see the **SIGN UP screen for less then a second** then re-directed inside the app.

How can I just make it >>> Splash Screen >> Inside the app (for registered user)
For non-registered user>>> Splash Screen >> Sign up

Please help and thank you. I attached images for more support
[image: Splash Screen]
[image: Registered user sees sign up for a sec]

Comment: Post your code what you have tried

Comment: Can you please share image of your storyboard??

Comment: If you don't want the sign-up screen - don't show it, simple as that.